# Update shopify cart with customized product image

Tags: php, shopify, liquid, shopify-app

I'm working on Shopify public app creation. I have customized a product image and store that image link in a meta field of that particular product.

I want to show the customized image I had created when adding the product to cart and other order product listing section without updating actual product image.

How can that possible? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, you could modify the template so to use a URL stored in the metafield e.g.

```
{% assign custom_images = product.metafields.custom_images %}
{% assign key = 'url' %}

<img src="{{ custom_images.url }}" />>
```